# Average Amplitude (in dB) every second of audio file in Librosa

Tags: python, numpy, librosa

I want to get an average amplitude of the sound file for every second. For example the average amplitude of 0-1 sec,1-2 sec, and so on. I tried reducing the sample rate to 1 but the value drops to 0 in that case.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from glob import glob
import librosa as lr

y, sr = lr.load(file,sr=10)
print(y)
print(len(y))
time = np.arange(0,len(y))/sr
print(len(time))
print(time,y)

print(y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(time,y)
ax.set(xlabel='Time(s)',ylabel='sound amplitude')
plt.show()
```

**Note: I'm trying to get the amplitude value in dB. Really new with Librosa, would appreciate any help:)**

Comment: How will you define dB?

Comment: Are you actually interested in the peak value over the second?

Comment: Yes Peak value should solve the problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do average amplitude, which is usually going to be 0.

```
y, sr = lr.load(file)
second = []
for s in range(0,len(y),sr):
    second.append( y[s:s+sr].mean() )
```

This will do average `abs` amplitude.

```
y, sr = lr.load(file)
second = []
for s in range(0,len(y),sr):
    second.append( np.abs(y[s:s+sr]).mean())
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer, Let me check them and see if this solves my problem.

Comment: You might want to try `np.max` instead, to get the peak value.